# Kindle fire stuck in "Parenting mode"

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

I unfortunately changed my Kindle settings to Parenting and know find it difficult to use. I can't get access to all my files and documents, videos, internet and many more.

I want to register for a new account but can't get access to my the main settings when I go to the MORE... it just open a page and says "manage child settings", "set daily goals" and others.

I can't use the device now. How can I get this fixed?

Comment: Somewhere you can disable it by entering the parental control password.  IIRC, it's in Manage Child Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Kindle FreeTime, swipe down where the hotkeys are, then tap exit.